# JPanels arent moving around when I change the borderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am creating a calculator program using swing in eclipse.
There are a couple buttons 0-9, +, -, *, /, etc.
There are 3 panels that I have created so far. I need 5 and I want to put them like

```
clear /  -> Fifth panel
7 8 9 +  -> Fourth panel
4 5 6 -  -> Third panel
1 2 3 *  -> Second panel
0  =  .  -> First panel
```

But the buttons are overlapping or something and I cant get them to separate

I tried different BorderLayout.____ but they still arent separating
for ex:

```
add(First, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
add(Second, BorderLayout.EAST);
add(Third, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;   // swing offers many GUI components
import java.awt.event.*;

public class calculator
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {           
        GUI myCalc = new GUI();
        myCalc.setTitle("Calculator");
        myCalc.setSize(350, 500);
        myCalc.setVisible(true);
        myCalc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}

class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener
{
    JPanel myFirstPanel;

    JButton zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine,
            dot, backspace, plus, minus, multiply, divide, clear;

    JLabel msgLabel;

    JTextField textBox;


    GUI()
    {
        super();

        JPanel First = new JPanel();
        JPanel Second = new JPanel();
        JPanel Third = new JPanel();

        one = new JButton("1");
        two = new JButton("2");
        three = new JButton("3");
        four = new JButton("4");
        five = new JButton("5");
        six = new JButton("6");
        seven = new JButton("7");
        eight = new JButton("8");
        nine = new JButton("9");

        First.add(one);
        First.add(two);
        First.add(three);
        Second.add(four);
        Second.add(five);
        Second.add(six);
        Third.add(seven);
        Third.add(eight);
        Third.add(nine);

        add(First, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        add(Second, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(Third, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(First);
        add(Second);
        add(Third);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) // when mouse leaves
    {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) // when mouse enters
    {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) // when mouse is released after press
    {

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) // when mouse is clicked
    {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) // when mouse is pressed and held
    {

    }

}
```

I keep getting 789 buttons only :/ 
I am new to this so any explaination will help. Thank you

Comment: My first "gut feeling" is to place all the buttons within a single panel and use a `GridLayout`, which should accomplish the basic look you're looking for.  If that does quite meet your needs you're going to need to use a `GridBagLayout`, which will give you more flexibility and control over the spanning

Comment: Will try that, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a "general" recommendations, you could explore other layout managers.  Eventually, you're going to get to a point where you'll want to explore `GridBagLayout`.

This is by far the most flexible layout manager, which makes it also the most complicated.

You should start with [How to layout components within a container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) in particular

[image: All your button belong to us]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            // First line
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 3;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(new JButton("Clear"), gbc);

            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 3;
            add(new JButton("/"), gbc);

            // Second line
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(new JButton("7"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("8"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("9"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("+"), gbc);

            // Third line
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            add(new JButton("4"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("5"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("6"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("-"), gbc);

            // Second line
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 3;
            add(new JButton("1"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("2"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("3"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("*"), gbc);

            // Last line
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 4;
            add(new JButton("0"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            add(new JButton("="), gbc);
            gbc.gridx += 2;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            add(new JButton("."), gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Looks pretty solid tbh. will learn how to program the buttons too and add the display. thank you!